# Efforts made to reduce the amount of CFC

Tags: environmental-chemistry, green-chemistry

Till now I have heard $\ce{CO2}$ is the main reason of global warming. I have studied the remedies to control $\ce{CO2}$ many times through books, awarness programs, etc.

But today I learned about Chlorofluorocarbon ($\ce{CFC}$). It have **38 million** times more "Global Warming Potential" than $\ce{CO2}$    according to UN.

In my book they have mention the sources of $\ce{CFC}$ like aerosols, refrigerators, air-conditioners, foams in fire extinguisher, etc.

But it does not tell what effort we should make or scientist are doing in order to reduce harmful of $\ce{CFC}$.

I have heard that $\ce{CFC}$ is replaced by [1,1,2,2-Tetrachloroethane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1,1,2,2-Tetrachloroethane), nothing else.

So, I want to know what else we are trying to reduce harmful effect of  $\ce{CFC}$?

Comment: I don't know this topic well enough to provide a proper answer, but I believe that the problem with CFC's lies mostly in their ability to form chlorine radicals at high altitude.  These act as catalysts to destroy ozone.  The volume of CFC released each year is nowhere near as much as CO2.  They've been banned in the US for about 2 decades outside of medical and research purposes.  Elsewhere in the world, I don't know.  The 38 million figure seems high.  [Global Warming Potential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global-warming_potential) has a list of chemicals ranked in this way.

Comment: @JasonPatterson About 38 million i don't know, but this what my textbook says. And it is compared to CO2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After learning more about environmental chemistry I got this.

On 16 september 1987, 95 countries accepted not to use ODS(Ozone Depleting Substances)  after signing Mortal Protocol. Later other countries also accepted it.

After that United Nation have decided to celebrate 16 september as "Ozone protection day" at international level to spread awareness.